# Compute total bytes transferred from Elasticsearch logs based on highest sequence number

Tags: elasticsearch

Working with Elastic Search 5.  Documents are data transfer logs (millions), with the following relevant fields:

- Session, number (unique per session)
- Sequence, number (ordinal, per packet, range from 1st to last packet of the session, values from 0 - 100000000....)
- Bytes, number, total transferred (count of bytes, grows with sequence, is the total bytes transferred in the session thus far)

Desired result of query:

- Total count of Unique Sessions (solved this one)
- Total bytes transferred - this is where I am failing.  It is necessary to select the document with the largest Sequence Number for a given unique Session Number, and add the Bytes Transferred to a roll-up sum.

Example documents:

```
{"session":1,"sequence":0,"bytes":512}
{"session":2,"sequence":0,"bytes":323}
{"session":1,"sequence":1,"bytes":1287}
{"session":1,"sequence":2,"bytes":3456}
{"session":2,"sequence":1,"bytes":800}
{"session":3,"sequence":0,"bytes":200}
{"session":1,"sequence":3,"bytes":4000}
```

Desired example results:

- Session Total: 3  (sum of unique 'session' values - session 1,2,3)
- Bytes Total:   5000 (sum of 'bytes' from the last/ greatest sequence number of each unique session)

I can get the Session Total with a similar query:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
 "size":0,
 "query" : {
    ... my query details
 },
 "aggs" : {
  "distinct_sessions" : {
   "cardinality" : {
    "field" : "session"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the sum from those unique sessions, particularly with the the requirement to get the highest sequence number only.  I've tried variations with top_hits, size 1, descending, but I cannot get correct.

Anyone else tried to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of using a `terms` aggregation on session goes in the right direction. This query should provide you what you need:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sessions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "session"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_hits": {
          "size": 1,
          "sort": {
            "sequence": "desc"
          },
          "_source": [
            "bytes"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't need to keep all the session history, you could simply use the session id as the document id, that way you'd only have the latest session data in your documents and the problem solves itself that way.